# With FluentValidation, get the index of the wrong elements

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

With FluentValidation, I'm trying to get the index of the invalid element in the list but I only get the error from the RuleFor.

```
RuleForEach(m => m.Attendees)
  .OverrideIndexer((_, _, element, _) => $"<{element}>")
  .ChildRules(a =>
  {
    a.RuleFor(at => at.Email).NotNull().EmailAddress();
  })
  .OverridePropertyName("Attendees")
  .WithMessage("At least 1 attendee is invalid.");
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the validation inside the `ChildRules` block.

```
RuleForEach(m => m.Attendees)
    .ChildRules(a =>
    {
        a.RuleFor((model, element, context) =>
        {
            var index = ((List<Attendee>)context.ParentContext.InstanceToValidate).IndexOf(element);
            // You can now use the 'index' variable as needed
            return element.Email != null && element.Email.Contains("example");
        }).WithMessage("Invalid email for attendee at index {Index}");
    })
    .OverridePropertyName("Attendees")
    .WithMessage("At least 1 attendee is invalid.");
```

Adjust the logic inside the RuleFor as needed for your specific validation criteria.

Note: This assumes that `Attendees` is a `List<Attendee>`. If your collection is of a different type, adjust the cast accordingly.

```
RuleForEach(m => m.Attendees)
    .OverrideIndexer((_, _, element, _) => $"<{element}>")
    .ChildRules(a =>
    {
        a.RuleFor(at => at.Email)
            .NotNull().WithMessage((element, context) => $"Email for attendee at index {context.Index} is required.")
            .EmailAddress().WithMessage((element, context) => $"Email for attendee at index {context.Index} is not a valid email address.");
    })
    .OverridePropertyName("Attendees")
    .WithMessage("At least 1 attendee is invalid.");
```